# Test::Unit should equivalent of RSpec should_receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd, testunit

I am writing some unit tests for my Ruby on Rails application. I would like to test that my model received a message to a particular method. In RSpec this is done with the `should_receive` incantation.

Is there an equivalent to Test::Unit that can do the same? If Test::Unit cannot do it, is there a tool I can use in concert with it to get that functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/). It is a gem that you can use with Test::Unit or Rspec (but I prefer the native rspeck mocking). It allows you to write something like

```
@post.stubs(:something).returns(:bla)
@post.expects(:something_else).raises(StandardError, "failed")
```

Hope this helps